# Spring Reactive Redis: PubSub does not work if the publisher or subscriber does not run from the same machine

Tags: redis, spring-webflux, lettuce, azure-redis-cache

I have two spring boot services running in two different VMs on two different virtual network.
One service runs on and pushes notifications to a channel in Azure RediscCache.

```
Optional<Long> hasMessageSent = redisStringTemplate.convertAndSend(syncQueue, GSON.toJson(data))
            .onErrorReturn(-1L).blockOptional(Duration.ofMinutes(BLOCK_MINUTES));
if (!hasMessageSent.isPresent() || hasMessageSent.get() < 0) {
   LOG.warn("Unable to send the sync message.");
   return false;
}
```

2nd service subscribes to the above channel to receive the notifications.

```
public void subscriberToChannel() {
    LOG.debug("Subscribing to channel " + syncQueue);

    redisTemplate.listenToChannel(syncQueue).name("SYNCQUEUER").doOnNext(msg -> {

    LOG.debug("New message received: '" + msg.toString());

    buildOrUpdateNotifications(getNotification(msg.getMessage()));

}).doOnError(e -> LOG.error("Error while listening at the channel, will continue.", e)).subscribe();
```

}

The above setup works fine if I have both publisher and subscriber run from the same machine.
When I moved the publisher i.e.,1st service to a VM; subscriberi.e., 2nd service has stopped receiving the messages.

I could see from the redis console that publisher is indeed pushing the messages to the channel but subscriber does not receive them.

I can confirm that in all the scenarios, publisher and subscribe are connected to the same Azure Redis Cache instance.

While it does not make sense for the subscriber not to receive the message, I am wondering, is there something I am missing here? does channel have any limitation on the network it is running on?

Comment: Just curious: SPRING_REDIS_HOST what do you have for this ?

Comment: @vins spring.redis.host is set to azure redis cache server name. Connection to the server is established in a right way, I could see that in the logs and other cache related code is working fine.

Comment: Because you are using a vm, I suggest using `wireshark` for packet capture analysis to ensure that the vm message is sent and the other vm receives the message. Then consider the program or settings.

Comment: Believe it or not, publisher was publishing the data to the channel notification:sync whereas subscriber was listening at "notification:sync" - just difference in quotes - redis treated them as two different channels.

Comment: @VenkateshLaguduva, as per your latest reply you found the root cause to be channel name difference. Were you able to fix it or still need someone to look into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is not exactly an answer but one may want to know that Redis treats "mychannel" and mychannel as two different channels - one with quotes and another one without quotes.